# How to specify range with NSPredicate in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nspredicate

I want to query sqllite table by specifying a range. So it's like give me all records whose id column between 3000 and 3010.

I tried what Apple recommends, but it didn't work. Here is what I tried and failed.

```
NSPredicate *betweenPredicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"attributeName BETWEEN %@", @[@1, @10]];
```

I have 2 strings called start and end. I updated Apple's example as following.

```
NSPredicate *betweenPredicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%@ BETWEEN %@", columnName, @[start,end]];
```

When I executeFetchRequest with the above predicate I get 0 records even though the table has records matching the predicate. Can someone point where I go wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the `%K` format specifier for attribute names:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K BETWEEN %@", columnName, @[start,end]];
```

If that does not work (I have never used "BETWEEN" for Core Data fetch requests), you 
could replace it by the equivalent predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K >= %@ AND %K <= %@",
         columnName, start, columnName, end];
```

Comment: When I use %K instead of %@, then I get [__NSCFString constantValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error. The second example you gave works. Thanks

Comment: @neo: You are welcome! - (I vaguely remember that "BETWEEN" does not work with Core Data, but I am not sure.)

Comment: `BETWEEN` works perfectly with Core Data : `%K BETWEEN { %f , %f }`, and is about 10x faster than : `%K <= %f && %K >= %f`. Here is the link to apple developer [Predicate Formatting guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)