# Why isnt my NSPredicate working?

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm new to iOS development and I'm trying to add a predicate to my NSFetchRequest() in order to filter out items located nearby the user's current location. However, it doesnt seem to be working and the NSFetchRequest returns empty.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemLatitude BETWEEN {%d, %d}", (latitude-10), (latitude+10))
```

If I remove the predicate the query returns all items so fetch does work, but not the predicate it seems. There's probably something really basic wrong here and I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: `latitude` is usually a `Double`, not an `Int`. `%d` is the placeholder for `Int`

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "itemLatitude BETWEEN %@", [(latitude-10), (latitude+10)])`?

Comment: Some time ago I left a comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020234/how-to-specify-range-with-nspredicate-in-objective-c/18020486#comment26355791_18020486 that "BETWEEN" might not work with Core Data fetch requests. I don't know if that is (still) true, but you might try `"itemLatitude >= %d AND itemLatitude <= %d"` instead (or `%f` if that are floats, as vadian said).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

`let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemLatitude BETWEEN %@", [(latitude-10), (latitude+10)])`

For more details on how use BETWEEN comparison see [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) "Basic Comparisons" part.

Otherwise, you can code you predicate like this :

`let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemLatitude>%f AND itemLatitude<%f", (latitude-10), (latitude+10))`

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your predicate seems to be in the string formating, as @vadian mentioned. Replacing `%d` to `%f` makes it work. However, I let you here a little tip for debugging this kind of Predicate issues in the future:

`NSPredicate`'s `description` method will return you the string of the final Predicate being applied.

```
NSPredicate(format: "itemLatitude BETWEEN {%f, %f}", (latitude-10), (latitude+10)).description
NSPredicate(format: "itemLatitude BETWEEN {%f, %f}", (latitude-10), (latitude+10)).description
```

shows in a playground

```
itemLatitude BETWEEN {0, 0}
itemLatitude BETWEEN {13.45, 33.45}
```

@ben-messaoud-mahmoud's formating seems also appropriate for this predicate:

```
NSPredicate(format: "itemLatitude BETWEEN %@", [(latitude-10), (latitude+10)]).description
```

will also have as result:

```
itemLatitude BETWEEN {13.45, 33.45}
```

and is a more clear answer.

Cheers!